# Converting numbers to hexadecimal ASCII characters in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am currently working on an assignment where I need to write an assembly-language subroutine called "hexasc" that converts numbers in the range of 0 through 15 into a printable ASCII-coded character ('0' through '9', or 'A' through 'F', depending on the number). I am using the MARS simulator.

I have attempted to write the subroutine using basic assembly language instructions such as "li" and "move", but I am having trouble getting the desired output. Here is the code I have written so far:

`hexasc: li $v0, 48 add $v0, $a0 jr $ra`

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to correctly implement this subroutine. I am particularly struggling with converting the input numbers to their corresponding ASCII characters without using any registers such as s0-s7, gp, sp, fp, and ra.

This is what I have right now:

`# hexmain.asm

```
.text
```

main:
li  $a0,0       # change this to test different values

```
jal hexasc      # call hexasc
nop         # delay slot filler (just in case)  

move    $a0,$v0     # copy return value to argument register

li  $v0,11      # syscall with v0 = 11 will print out
syscall         # one byte from a0 to the Run I/O window
```

stop:   j   stop        # stop after one run
nop         # delay slot filler (just in case)

hexasc:             # You can write your own code for hexasc here`

Comment: Surely you are allowed to use conditional branching? Just check if the value is greater than 9 and then add a different constant that takes you to the letters.

Comment: You don't have to think in assembly to do this.  Manipulating numbers and characters can be done in any language, so work out the algorithm in a language that you know, then take that algorithm to assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this for a moment.

```
Number    Ascii (hex)
0            30
1            31
2            32
3            33
4            34
5            35
6            36
7            37
8            38
9            39
A            41
B            42
C            43
D            44
E            45
F            46
```

So we see a simple pattern: If our 4-bit number is greater than 0x39, add 0x37 to the digit. Otherwise, add 0x30. (You may need to do `andi $a0,$a0,0x0F` to chop off everything beyond the lowest 4 bits.)

EDIT: I didn't really do a good job of explaining why we add 0x37 to the number if it's greater than 9.

```
0x0A + 0x37 = 0x41 (ascii code of 'A')
0x0B + 0x37 = 0x42 (ascii code of 'B')
etc.
```